# Newbie with yellow/falling avocado tree leaves

Tags: trees, diagnosis, leaves, tree-care, avocado

First time newbie here:

I've received an avocado tree as a gift no so long ago (April 3rd) since I always wanted to have one (although planting it myself from scratch hehe). However, my plant has been having some problems since I had it. I'll list out all the information I can so it'd be easier to explain. It's a Hass plant.

- I've watered it twice since I received it (the 3rd and the 8th of April) (with tap water, my bad, and the pH in Madrid's tap water seems to be from 7 to 8,5 , so it's alkaline. http://madridsalud.es/control-del-agua-del-grifo/)
- The climate here is cold these last couple of days, but I leave the window closed during the night (Madrid, going 5 Celsius to 15 these last couple of days.
- I have not used any fertilizer, but as far as I can understand, I might need an iron fertilizer due to the problem I have.

Some leaves have turned yellow and then brown. The location of these leaves were not in the bottom but in the middle of the plant, so it doesn't seem to be too much water. The first 2 leaves that were too brown are still "watery" sort to speak. They're not dry. The 2 other leaves that are also now brown ARE dry.

Reading online, I should feel that the soil around the tree is at least a bit compact when I press it and it does feel that way, so I'm not sure about watering it even more because it doesn't feel that it needs to be watered.

I've tried to notice any bug on the underside of the leaf or in the top, but I don't see anything.

And unfortunately, I don't have any external area to leave the plant because I live on a high floor.

Could it also be a change in the environment due to the different location now?

I also *leave* some pictures for you to see.

Any recommendations? Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Plants don't suddenly go from being healthy to leaves going brown and dropping off in a week just because they need fertilizer, or because they get attacked by pests or diseases.

I've never grown an avocado, but I would bet the cause is that with the temperatures you mentioned, it was in a cold air when it was moved from somewhere else to your house, and that has damaged it.

Just keep it at the right temperature, give it a normal amount of water, and wait. If the cold shock has killed it there is nothing you can do anyway, and if not, it will gradually recover and start growing again in a few weeks.

Don't start experimenting with fertilizer, iron supplements, etc until it is growing again. That will just give the plant another shock while it is still recovering from the first one.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much! I'll wait then for the plant to recover a bit before doing anything.